# Challenges to learn jemalloc exploitation on FreeBSD

Tags: exploit, heap

I'm studying this phrack article: http://www.phrack.org/issues/68/10.html

Very interesting but the only valid way to be confident with an exploitation technique is an hands-on.

I'm searching for some pwn challenges about jemalloc exploitation (i prefer on FreeBSD), can someone link me some binaries?

Comment: While this is related to reverse engineering, it's not a good fit for the Q&A format. I suggest to bring this up in [our site chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7992/reverse-engineering) as that's a somewhat more free-form forum. In order to give you the [required privilege](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) I'll upvote this question.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it's open-ended and not a good fit for a Q&A site like this one. Please ask the question in our site chat as that is a little more informal (see my other comment). With a reputation of 20 that should not be an issue. The [ReverseEngineering Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ReverseEngineering/) would be another more free-form alternative to the Q&A format on StackExchange.